# Can build and run on Visual Studio but cannot Publish

Tags: asp.net-core, build, .net-core, publish, release

I am having a weird situation where I cannot publish my final Web project. Here is the project structure:

`Foo.Services.Common`: this is shared library: `.NET Standard 2.0.3`, `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core 2.1.0` with the class `DefaultWebSettings` defined.

`Foo.Services.Common.Razor`: Razor Class Library, has reference back to `Foo.Services.Common` and uses `DefaultWebSettings`: `NETStandard.Library 2.0.3`, `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 2.1.0` and some other ASP.NET Core related package (static files, Configuration)

`Foo.Services.Api`: ASP.NET Core API only (no View, no Razor), has reference back to `Foo.Services.Common`. Publish well. Uses: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0`, `Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.0`.

`Foo.Services.Web`: front end project. This one is the one I cannot publish! This one has references to both `Common` projects. Uses: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0`, `Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.0`

However, upon publish, this one shows up:

[image]

> The type or namespace name 'DefaultWebSettings' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The error location is in a file of `Foo.Services.Common.Razor` project, NOT the `Web` project.

Funnily, Visual Studio perfectly works even with IntelliSense and Go to Definition:

[image]

I can build in both Debug/Release mode, run with/without debug any project in the solution well. Moreover, publishing `Foo.Services.Common.Razor` works without any problem!

In short: I cannot publish my `Web` project and have no idea what is the problem. I have tried:

- Clean/Build.
- Delete/Re-add references.
- Manually delete all obj and bin folders.

Please show me what I may missing.

Comment: Have you checked all of your *.json files for any errors? This can sometimes cause unusual behavior.

Comment: @AperioOculus Hmm, they seems fine to me. I don't have any .Release.json file. Moreover, `Release` mode builds fine, only Publish does not work.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I had to remove Reference of the `Common` from `Common.Razor` and `Web` projects. I guess they could not build because of some conflict between .NET Standard and .NET Core. Had to copy all code of `Common` into `Common.Razor`.